# NullReferenceException was unhandled.

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I am a beginner at programming and I'm getting a `NullReferenceException` error. What could be the problem?

```
DataRow dRow = DS.Tables["tblLogin"].Rows[0];

dRow.BeginEdit();
dRow["PASSWORD"] = txtNew.Text;

dRow.EndEdit();

Cmd = new SqlCommand("Update tblLogin set PASSWORD = @PASSWORD where USERNAME = " + txtUser.Text, sConn);

Cmd.Parameters.Add("@PASSWORD", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "PASSWORD");

DA.UpdateCommand = Cmd;
DA.Update(DS, "tblLogin");

MessageBox.Show("Record Updated!", "Payroll System", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
```

Comment: Which line in happens? you can use try and catch..

Comment: I would bet your DataTable "tblLogin" is null.

Comment: DataRow dRow = DS.Tables["tblLogin"].Rows[0]; - On this line.

Comment: You Need to make sure you have initialised DA and DS before you try to make a reference to iti.e. DA.UpdateCommand = Cmd;

Answer (score 4):

You have an uninitalized variable in your code (variable with value `null`). If you try to access a member of this variable, you will get this exception.

Looking at it, it could be either `DS` or `DA`, because you don't show how you set the values for these two. Can you show us the code where it is initalized?

Also the exception will tell you the line where the error occurred, which will also help in determining the source of the error.

**Edit:**
According to your comments, it seems `DA` is not set to any value, alsomake sure that the table `tblLogin` exists in the `DataSet`.

Comment: `public partial class Account : Form
    {
        SqlConnection sConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Amiel_01\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\Softeng\\Softeng\\dbPayroll.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
        SqlDataAdapter DA;
        DataSet DS = new DataSet();
        SqlCommand Cmd;`

Comment: What value does DA have? It seems you don't initalize it

Comment: SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from tblLogin", sConn); @aKzenT

Answer (score 0):

- Set a breakpoint at the first line of the function.
- Once you get there, press `Ctrl+Alt+E` to bring up the exception settings box.
- Check the box to break on all Common Language Runtime exceptions. Then
- Hit `F5` to continue running. When the exception is thrown, you will get a marker of exactly where.